# How to position the background image to fill the screen?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am trying to have a background image to fill the screen and it doesn't go to the top of the screen whatever simulator / real device I use it always leaves a blank space, I have used the auto layout with constraints to the top and every possible constraint and haven't solved the problem, note that I am using an add banner with takes up the blank spot whet it is running. This is the code I have been using

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let yourImage = UIImage(named: "fond320x480.png")
        let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
        self.view.addSubview(imageview)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageview)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `imageview` to fill the screen then:

```
imageview.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(imageview)
```

But if you want `yourimage` to fill your `imageview` then you should set content mode of `imageview` to fill:

```
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

and then of course add your image and add view as subview

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Superian007 , I used this but it has now covered everything else (buttons labels etc ) and it is still placed correctly in the document outline when I am in the main storyboard

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. So you don't want to fill the screen with your image?

Comment: Yes, I want it to fill the screen but it as a background image so I want all the buttons , labels etc to be on top of it

Comment: Then you have to insert your view with image under views you just mentioned. 

Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:belowSubview:

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, Hope it will work for you.

set `UIImageView` `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` as below :

```
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```